# Need help - Could not allocate space Error while saving Erwin data model (attached pic)

Tags: sql-server, erwin

[image: Error]

I am getting this error when I am trying to save my data model in Erwin. The database for Erwin is SQL server installed on windows server.

I am not from SQL server background. Need some help.

Comment: The disk is full. Or your primary file group has been restricted to a certain size.

Comment: What things do I need to do? Do I have to contact DBA to perform any activity? I am just a user.

Comment: Yes you should contact your DBA, it's better to attach the image with the error too

Comment: I have raised this issue with DBA. Thanks

Comment: are you trying to save the model or forward engineer the model ? Saving the erwin project won't give this error. probably, you are trying to forward engineer, and the erwin tool is executing the DDL. Please, check what operation you are trying to do with Erwin.